# Which site has <a> link to my site?

Tags: javascript

I have a site, let's say [www.example.com](http://www.google.com)

An unknown site has a link to my site.

Can I find out automatically where the link is coming from by running a script on [www.example.com](http://www.google.com)? window.opener or window.parent?

Please do not think about browser debugging tools, browser extensions or running javascript by user by writing it to the url bar.

Comment: you can check `referer`

Comment: Are you asking how to scan the Web for links to your site, or how to find out, on a page of yours, what was the referring page if the page was reached by following a link at some other site? These are quite different questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.referrer` gives you the URI of the page that linked to the current page.

[more informative link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157396/how-do-you-get-the-url-referer-via-a-javascript-include)

Comment: Assuming that the browser has not been configured so that it does not send referrer information,

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Hmm, yes, but only if all users did that would it not work for this purpose.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski, that depends on what the purpose is.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: Yup, I'm guessing it's to convert 'unknown site' to 'known site'.  Because otherwise the question language would be something else like how can I tell users coming from site a vs users from site b, dunno...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `link:` operator in a Google search?

E.g. Googling for [`link:"stackoverflow.com/questions/2157396/how-do-you-get-the-url-referer-via-a-javascript-include"`](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=link:%22stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F2157396%2Fhow-do-you-get-the-url-referer-via-a-javascript-include%22)